# Mount a windows share into Linux - failed No such file or directory although accessible in windows file explorer

Tags: linux, mount, samba

I tried to mount a windows share into the Linux server by using the following command:

```
mount -t cifs -v -o username=myname,password=mypassword //somename.net/the/path/to/the/directory /my/local/path
```

Then it failed with error:
mount error (2): No such file or directory

Also, I tried to mount other paths:

```
//somename.net/the/path/to/the - mount error(13) Permission Denied
//somename.net/the/path/to - mount error(13) Permission Denied
//somename.net/the/path - success
```

I highly suspect that first 2 paths are not allowed to access by me as the admin added some restriction on them.

Also, I can confirm that the path I want to access is existing as I can see it in Windows File Explorer.

Any ideas why? really appreciated

---

More Failed Attempts:

1. `-o username=name,password=pass,domain=mydomain,vers=1.0`: Mount error: Server abruptly closed the connection.
2. `-o username=name,password=pass,domain=mydomain with vers=2.0 or 2.1 or 3.0`: failed with mount error (2) No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding “List Folder” permission to `//somename.net/the/path/to/the` and `//somename.net/the/path/to`.

So does it mean the folder cannot be mounted and considered as not existing if the user does not have any permission to its parent folders?

Comment: Nice! Typically a directory needs to have what is called in Linux, execute permissions. That means the directory needs to be executable to see what is in it. I am mainly a macOS and Linux person but it sounds like “List Folder” works in a similar way.

Comment: hey @Giacomo1968 thanks for the clarification. it makes more sense now